# Why my javascript drag resize box doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, css

This is my code. I prefer to create a resize box purely on javascript without jquery.The code enable me to resize the width of paragraph when i drag it over but it seems like it don't work as expected.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

div{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;

}

p{
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
</style>
<script>
window.onload = function(){

    document.body.onmousedown = function(event){

         var mouseStartX = event.clientX;
         var mouseStartY = event.clientY;
       var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

       var para = document.createElement("p");

       div[0].appendChild(para);



         document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[1].style.top = mouseStartY;
              document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[1].style.left = mouseStartX;



        document.body.onmousemove = function(event){

            if(para){

            document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[1].style.width = event.clientY - mouseStartY;



            }


        }

       document.body.onmouseup = function(){
            div[0].removeChild(para);

       }


    };

};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

my problem is I expect that the p will keep on enlarge as I drag my mouse to the right,but it only work when I drag to a certain point

Comment: If you don't explain exactly what it was that you expected, it may be difficult for anyone to help.

Comment: What is happening? Do you get any errors?

Comment: @Pointy my problem is I expect that the p will keep on enlarge as I drag my mouse to the right,but it only work when I drag to a certain point.

Comment: What is this "certain point"? JavaScript can't follow your mouse outside the browser window.

Comment: i mean do that work perfectly for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only attempt to answer your question because your wording is a bit vague. However, I copy and pasted your code into a test HTML file that I loaded into my web browser, and I can guess what the problem that you're having is. The problem is that the `p` enlarges as you drag your cursor, but it doesn't enlarge all the way so that the right border is in line with your cursor.

First of all, in your `document.body.onmousemove` function:

```
document.body.onmousemove = function (event) {
    if (para) {
        document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[1].style.width = event.clientY - mouseStartY;
    }
}
```

You wrote `event.clientY` and `mouseStartY` when I think that you meant `event.clientX` and `mouseStartX`. However, you are also modifying a CSS rule, so you have to append the unit `px` to the end of the width:

```
document.body.onmousemove = function (event) {
    if (para) {
        document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[1].style.width = (event.clientX - mouseStartX) + "px";
        // The parentheses are technically not required; I put them there for clarity.
    }
}
```

The same goes for these two lines of code:

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[1].style.top = mouseStartY;
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[1].style.left = mouseStartX;
```

You forgot to include the units. Just add `+ "px"` before the end of each line:

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[1].style.top = mouseStartY + "px";
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[1].style.left = mouseStartX + "px";
```

Additionally, it is better just to delete `window.onmousemove` and `window.onmouseup` in your `window.onmouseup` function instead of checking for `para` in your `window.onmousemove` function. Even after you remove `para` from the `div`, it still evaluates to `true`.

Finally, instead of modifying the stylesheet via `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[1]`, you could just directly edit the style of `para` by using `para.style.width` instead of `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[1].style.width`.

I rewrote your `window.onload` function like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.body.onmousedown = function(event){
        var mouseStartX = event.clientX,
            mouseStartY = event.clientY,
            div = document.getElementsByTagName("div"),
            para = document.createElement("p");
        div[0].appendChild(para);
        para.style.top = mouseStartY + "px";
        para.style.left = mouseStartX + "px";
        document.body.onmousemove = function(event){
            para.style.width = event.clientX - mouseStartX + "px";
            //para.style.height = event.clientY - mouseStartY + "px";
            // Uncomment the line above if you want to drag the height, too.
        }
        document.body.onmouseup = function(){
            div[0].removeChild(para);
            document.body.onmousemove = null;
            document.body.onmouseup = null;
        }
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
document.body.onmousemove = function (event) {
    if (para) {
        document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[1].style.width = event.clientX - mouseStartX;
    }
}
```

instead of:

```
document.body.onmousemove = function (event) {
    if (para) {
        document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[1].style.width = event.clientY - mouseStartY;
    }
}
```

Otherwise, the `p` element will only resize on vertical movement, not horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-browser compatible solution also using window scroll offset and mouse movement in all four quadrants:

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
    var para = null, mouseStartX, mouseStartY; //top & left coordinates of paragraph
    document.body.onmousedown = function (event) {
        if (para) {
            return;
        }
        event = event || window.event; // for IE8/7 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790725/javascript-track-mouse-position#7790764
        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.scrollY#Notes
        var scrollX = (window.pageXOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageXOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollLeft;
        var scrollY = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
        mouseStartX = event.clientX + scrollX;
        mouseStartY = event.clientY + scrollY;
        para = document.createElement("p");
        div.appendChild(para);
        para.style.top = mouseStartY + 'px';
        para.style.left = mouseStartX + 'px';
        para.style.width = '0px';
        para.style.height = '0px';
    };
    document.body.onmousemove = function (event) {
        if (!para) {
            return;
        }
        event = event || window.event;
        var scrollX = (window.pageXOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageXOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollLeft;
        var scrollY = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
        var mouseCurrentX = event.clientX + scrollX;
        var mouseCurrentY = event.clientY + scrollY;
        if (mouseCurrentX >= mouseStartX) {
            para.style.left = mouseStartX + 'px';
            para.style.width = (mouseCurrentX - mouseStartX) + 'px';
        } else {
            para.style.left = mouseCurrentX + 'px';
            para.style.width = (mouseStartX - mouseCurrentX) + 'px';
        }
        if (mouseCurrentY >= mouseStartY) {
            para.style.top = mouseStartY + 'px';
            para.style.height = (mouseCurrentY - mouseStartY) + 'px';
        } else {
            para.style.top = mouseCurrentY + 'px';
            para.style.height = (mouseStartY - mouseCurrentY) + 'px';
        }
    };
    document.body.onmouseup = function () {
        div.removeChild(para);
        para = null;
    };
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hMbCF/1/

http://jsfiddle.net/hMbCF/1/show/