# Resizing a div on mousemove?

Tags: jquery

I'm changing the width of my div based upon mouse movement.

This is called when mouse moves:

```
p.resize = function(e) {

    var w += e.clientX
    myDiv.css({width:w});

};
```

The problem is the width increases by a lot each time, I need to find out how much the mouse has moved relative to the last time it moved, so I can then increase my div by the amount.

I'm not sure how to implement this, could someone help?

Comment: capture the mouse position at regular intervals (settimeout or some such) and update then? related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790725/javascript-track-mouse-position

Comment: what if you just remove the `+` ?

Answer (score 0):

Script

```
$( "div" ).mousemove(function( event ) { 
     var w = (event.pageX < 250) ? event.pageX :250;
     var h = (event.pageY < 250) ? event.pageY :250;
     $(this).css({"width":w,"height":h});    
 });
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/UNJ9Z/1/