# How do I pass event variable/place a marker on the map - when binding done events in Datamaps & D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, datamaps

I'm working on a US map that's created with datamaps on d3. I want to place a marker on the selected states based on the mouse XY. The #map-bubble is the marker that I want to place on the map.

I'm not sure if I'm using the correct approach for doing this, but the way I've chosen - there doesn't seem to be a way to grab the mouse XY in the on click bind. The only alternative I've found is this way: [Javascript - Track mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790725/javascript-track-mouse-position) which seems cumbersome.

```
var map = new Datamap({
        element: document.getElementById("map"),
        scope: 'usa',
        fills: {
            defaultFill: "#ABDDA4",
            win: '#0fa0fa'
        },
        geographyConfig: {
    dataUrl: null, //if not null, datamaps will fetch the map JSON (currently only supports topojson)
    hideAntarctica: true,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#FDFDFD',
    popupTemplate: function(geography, data) { //this function should just return a string
        return '';
    },
    popupOnHover: false, //disable the popup while hovering
    highlightOnHover: true,
    highlightFillColor: '#FC8D59',
    highlightBorderColor: 'rgba(250, 15, 160, 0.2)',
    highlightBorderWidth: 2
},
data: {
    'TX': { fillKey: 'win' },
    'FL': { fillKey: 'win' },
    'NC': { fillKey: 'win' },
    'CA': { fillKey: 'win' },
    'NY': { fillKey: 'win' },
    'CO': { fillKey: 'win' }
},
done: function(datamap) {
    datamap.svg.selectAll('.datamaps-subunit').on('click', function(event, geography) {
        console.log(event.pageY)
        var bubbly = $("#map-bubble");      
        bubbly.css({
            position:"absolute", 
            top: event.pageY, 
            left: event.pageX 
        });
        console.log(bubbly)
            bubbly.fadeIn("slow");
        console.log(geography.properties.name);
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the mouse click event and get the `pageX` and `pageY`coordinates, you can use the global `d3.event` object. Read more about it [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#d3_event).

For your example, try replacing your `done` function with the following:

```
done: function(datamap) {
    datamap.svg.selectAll('.datamaps-subunit').on('click', function(geography) {
        console.log(d3.event.pageY)
        var bubbly = $("#map-bubble");      
        bubbly.css({
            position:"absolute", 
            top: d3.event.pageY, 
            left: d3.event.pageX 
        });
        console.log(bubbly)
            bubbly.fadeIn("slow");
        console.log(geography.properties.name);
    });
}
```

Notice how I also removed the first parameter, event.

Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/julenka/pen/lsfhw) showing a working example, and the [result](http://codepen.io/julenka/debug/lsfhw).