# record mouse movements with selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

Simple question - how can I make selenium IDE record all mousemove events? There doesn't seem to be an option to do that. Do I need another plugin/extension for that?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the exact path the mouse moves along in between clicks and hovers?

Comment: @jcfollower - yup. can this be done with selenium IDE?

Comment: I've never heard of that being done ... just the hovers and clicks (and I'm not too sure about the hovers).

Answer (score 0):

Selenium IDE won't auto-record this for you. But it looks like you might be able to use some javascript magic to record this: [Javascript - Track mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790725/javascript-track-mouse-position)

I'd question why you want this data. If it's to record coordinates to then write tests there are better ways to record where to click, etc by using locators.

Comment: Recording is easy, but how to replay? As to what I need the data for - my site makes decisions based on mouse movements (not hover over's), so I need it to test the logic.

Comment: site uses mouse movements how so? Do you just need to trigger certain events? mouseMoveAt might help here?