# Get click position on the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, offset

I am trying to get the position of the click when the user click whatever part of the window. I found [this code](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/get-x-y-mouse-coordinates/) in many tutorials but it seems not to work.

```
(function( $ ) {
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        $( window ).click(function( e ) {
            var offset = $(this).offset(),
                relativeX = (e.pageX - offset.left),
                relativeY = (e.pageY - offset.top);

                alert("X: " + relativeX + "  Y: " + relativeY);
        });
    });
})( jQuery );
```

Firefox console tells me "TypeError: offset is undefined" and I don't understand why it does not work.

Which is the right way to retrieve the click position on the window?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That code is really close to working. It will work correctly if you replace `$(this)` with `$(e.target)`. This will get the left and top offsets of the click event, not the `window` itself.

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(window).click(function(e) {
            var relativeX = (e.pageX - $(e.target).offset().left),
                relativeY = (e.pageY - $(e.target).offset().top);

                alert("X: " + relativeX + "  Y: " + relativeY);
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/IronFlare/7wsamt87/

Answer (score 2):

If you're clicking on the window like that, you don't really need an offset.

```
$(window).click(function (e) {

        alert("X: " + e.pageX + "  Y: " + e.pageY);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is assuming the wrong `this`;

In your listener, `this` will be `window`, but `$(window).offset();` makes no sense, which is why the method returns `null` or `undefined`.

Perhaps you meant to use `document.documentElement`, `document.body` or `e.target` which would be the `<html>`, `<body>` or the clicked node, respectively.

```
$(document.body).offset();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I hope to have find a solution
```

```js
function showCoords(event) {
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
    var coords = "X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = coords;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2 onclick="showCoords(event)">Click this heading to get the x (horizontal) and y (vertical) coordinates of the mouse pointer when it was clicked.</h2>

<p><strong>Tip:</strong> Try to click different places in the heading.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question is about the _click_ event, not _mousemove_. Also, how far back is this attempting to support? IE5?

Comment: Attribution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790725/javascript-track-mouse-position#answer-7790764

Comment: Stryner I have soon removed my comment, there is no need to keep this comment