# How can I observe the current section being viewed by a user in a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web

As a user views a web page, they navigate to different sections of the page by scrolling. In [Bootstrap's documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/), the `bs-docs-sidenav` list item changes color to reflect which section is currently 'active' (visible on screen).

- Does this type of observation have a name (or names)?
- Does the DOM have any properties that keep track of an element's location?
- If not, are there any common plug-ins/small libraries to take advantage of this information?

Comment: I think a similar question was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790725/javascript-track-mouse-position

Comment: Hi @neallred - the question you linked to is about tracking mouse position.   I am looking for resources that detail how to observe sections of a web page (sections are somtimes identifed with `<h2 id="mySection">My Section</h2>`) as they reach the top of the viewport.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport) is a similar question. My approach to track nodes that I am considering now would be to register each "section" and use the getBoundingClientRect function to track registered sections and determine which section is "active".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Bootstrap has a plugin called [Scrollspy](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy). The [`getBoundingClientRect` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) can be used to find an elements location.