# google bubble chart how to add HTML tooltip

Tags: charts, tooltip, google-visualization, bubble-chart

I have a Google chart: bubble chart.
I want to add a custom HTML tooltip, with the specified value relative to the point:

```
<div class="clearfix>
     <h3>Metric: []</h3>
     <h4>ID comes here: []</h4>
     <h4>X Axis Value comes here: []</h4>
     <h4>Y Axis Value comes here: []</h4>
     <h4>Volume comes here: []</h4>
</div>
```

Currently it shows a default tooltip, which is not arranged in the way i want. And I cannot edit the fields also.

I want to use Custom HTML tooltip, but sadly it is not supported by Google charts in bubble chart as of yet.

[image]

Any way to achieve the same.

**MY CODE**

[**JSFIDDLE Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/hup73gtv/)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1", {
            packages: ["corechart"]
        });
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
["ID", "X Axis Value", "Y Axis Value", "Metric", "Volume"],
["Range: 2-5", 3, 2.5, "Value Provider", 300],
["Range: 2-5", 4, 2.5, "Third Provider", 239],
["Range: 3-8", 3, 7.4, "Second Provider", 344],
["Range: 5-8", 5, 7.3, "Value Provider", 324],
["Range: 2-10", 9, 2.32, "Third Provider", 765],
["Range: 2-5", 5, 3, "Value Provider", 342],
]);

            var options = {
                title: 'Range Volume',
                hAxis: {
                    title: 'X Axis'
                },
                vAxis: {
                    title: 'Y Axis'
                },
                bubble: {
                    textStyle: {
                        fontSize: 11,
                                                    color:'transparent'
                    }
                }
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.BubbleChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 90vh;"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need some kind of mousetracker to know where tooltip should be shown and you need two listeners like this:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener chart, 'onmouseover', mouseoverHandler
google.visualization.events.addListener chart, 'onmouseout', mouseoutHandler
```

and you should add `id='tooltip'` to your tooltip with css like:

```
#tooltip {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: white;
  width: 350px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ddd;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ddd;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ddd;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

javascript:

```
var $tooltip = $('#tooltip')

mouseoverHandler = function(event) {
  metric = data.getValue(event.row, 3);
  id = data.getValue(event.row, 0);
  xAxis = data.getValue(event.row, 1);
  yAxis = data.getValue(event.row, 2);
  volume = data.getValue(event.row, 4);
  $tooltip.find('h3').append(metric);
  $tooltip.css({
    top: y,
    left: x
  }).show();
};

mouseoutHandler = function() {
  $tooltip.hide();
};
```

x and y are your mouse cords taken from some kind of mouse tracker like: [Javascript - Track mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790725/javascript-track-mouse-position).

`title = data.getValue(event.row, 3);` is line where you take data from your data from your chart and you have to insert this data into your tooltip the way you want it to be inserted. I hope it will help.

Comment: This doesn't explain how do i get row,column wise data what you are getting is just the title

Comment: Now it should show how to do this with all your columns, I've edited my answer.