# is it possible to prevent mouse cursor to leave a page when mouse down

Tags: javascript, jquery

It will be very good if you help me do this guys ! thanks a million in advance

```js
//Something like this I am thingking

$(document).on('mousedown',function(){
    //code that prevents cursor leaving a page
});
```

Comment: 1. Why would you even want to do that? 
2. Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

There is a pointer lock API that should do what you are looking for using `canvas.requestPointerLock || canvas.mozRequestPointerLock`

There is a demo [here](http://mdn.github.io/pointer-lock-demo/)

[Check out the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_Lock_API)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is possible to *prevent* mouse move.

But, an approach would be to track mouse x/y position and alert user when he's going off the page.

Look [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7790764/2159528) about mouse tracking.