# How to determine the clicked position within an element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there any way in JavaScript to determine the clicked position within the element or distance from left, right or center? I am not able to determine the position (left, center or right) of clicked area.

[image]

I have following table -

```
<tr id="ing-117">
    <td style="width: 15%; vertical-align: middle; display: none;"><img src="arrow-left.png" class="arrow left hidden"></td>
    <td style="width: 70%; text-align: left;" class="txt center lefted"><div class="in"></div>2 cups ice</td>
    <td style="width: 15%; vertical-align: middle;"><img src="arrow-right.png" class="arrow right hidden"></td>
</tr>
```

and here is my js code -

```
 $('.arrow').unbind('click')
        .bind('click', function(event, is_triggered){
            var th = $(this);
            var x = event.clientX;
            var y = event.clientY;
            console.log(x , y);
```

but when I click on 2nd `<td>` it prints `undefined undefined` in console

Please help, Thanks.

Comment: The event object (first argument to the event handler) has some properties that can help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790725/javascript-track-mouse-position Check this question out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the `offsetX` and `offsetY` properties from the click event that's passed to the click handler. Try this:

```js
$('div').click(function(e) {
  var clickX = e.offsetX;
  var clickY = e.offsetY;
  $('span').text(clickX + ', ' + clickY);
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #EEF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<span></span>
```

---

*Update*

The edited code in your question should work fine (even though you should be using `off()` and `on()` instead of `unbind()` and `bind()`). Have you checked the console for errors?

```js
 $('.arrow').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
   var th = $(this);
   var x = e.clientX;
   var y = e.clientY;
   console.log(x, y);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="ing-117">
    <td style="width: 15%; vertical-align: middle; display: none;">
      <img src="arrow-left.png" class="arrow left hidden">
    </td>
    <td style="width: 70%; text-align: left;" class="txt center lefted">
      <div class="in"></div>
      2 cups ice
    </td>
    <td style="width: 15%; vertical-align: middle;">
      <img src="arrow-right.png" class="arrow right hidden">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The code in your update should work fine, although you should use `off()` and `on()`. See my updated answer for a working example

Answer (score 0):

Use any of the mouse events (mousemove, mouseup, mousedown) and pass the *event* argument to a function. Inside the function, you can access the clientX & clientY properties to get the coordinates.

An example:

```
<div onmousemove="showCoords(event)"></div>

function showCoords(event) {
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
    var coor = "X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do by offset position of td and click position in window

```
$(document).on('click','td_selector',function(){
     alert(e.pageX-$(this).offset().left)+"::"+ (e.pageY-$(this).offset().top));
})
```