# Get absolute cursor position on screen, even when in iframe (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I need to get a cursor position on my page, but `e.clientX/e.clientY` are `undefined` when the cursor is inside the `iframe`.
The `iframe` is cross-platform, so I can't get its contents from my page, but I can modify its contents remotely though, make it post messages to parent window, for example.
How can I solve this, using pure Javascript, without jQuery or any other libraries?

Comment: `e.screenX/Y` should do the trick, though you might get unexpected values from multi-screen systems.

Comment: cover the `iframe` with a empty/transparent `div` with a higher `zIndex` and use mouse events from the div ;)

Comment: Hi, this link sould help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790725/javascript-track-mouse-position