# How to darken a CSS background image but keep area around cursor brighter

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I use CSS or JS to make a fixed background darker but keep the area around the cursor slightly lighter so it gives a flashlight type effect ? Cant seem to figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you paste your code?

Comment: Not managed any code yet as Im not sure if i should use some kind of mask or some kind of hover code

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within the question itself

Comment: oh ok thank you, sorry i didnt realise.

Comment: @ScottHunter without having any attempt or starting point from you, I can't help much. Check this out though, I think it is kind of what you are going for https://codepen.io/tomhodgins/pen/egWjBb

Answer (score 3):

Just create an overlay using a `<div>` or a pseudoelement ([`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) or [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)) and style it as your "torch" / "highlight"  using CSS. I would suggest using shadows, gradients or a combination of both, depending on the desired result.

Then, with JS, you can keep track of the cursor's position and move that overlay around following it or change its CSS properties' values (maybe using [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables), depending on your browser support needs), depending on your implementation.

If you go for the former, ideally you should be using [`window.requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) in order to get smoother transitions without harming performance.

Try to implement that yourself and, if you have issues with the implementation, come back and create another question with that specific issue. As some have pointed out in the comments, we are not supposed to write the code for you, especially when you haven't tried before (or at least you have not provided any evidence about it).

#### EDIT:

As it's been a few days since this question was created, I guess it's fine to post a working solution now, as I was curious myself to know how realistic this effect could be using just CSS.

@LambdaNinja's solution is a good starting point, but that doesn't look like a real torch.

The [Pen @JoshAdams posted in a comment](https://codepen.io/tomhodgins/pen/egWjBb) gets closer, but there's still room for improvement.

I have used [`window.requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables), [`background-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-blend-mode) and [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations).

```js
const W = window.innerWidth;
const H = window.innerHeight

function updateAnimationTiming() {
  const animationDuration = 5 + Math.random() * 5; // [5 - 10)
  const animationDelay = 5 + Math.random() * 10; // [5 - 15)
  
  window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--animationDuration', animationDuration + 's');
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--animationDelay', animationDelay + 's');
  });
  
  const timeout = (animationDuration + animationDelay) * 1000 - 100;
  
  setTimeout(updateAnimationTiming, timeout);
}

updateAnimationTiming();

document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    const X = e.clientX;
    const Y = e.clientY;

    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--cursorX', X + 'px');
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--cursorY', Y + 'px');

    const X2 = X - (12 * W / 100) * (X / W - 0.5);
    const Y2 = Y - (12 * W / 100) * (Y / H - 0.5);

    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--cursorX2', X2 + 'px');
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--cursorY2', Y2 + 'px');
  });
});
```

```css
:root {
  cursor: crosshair;
  --cursorX: 50vw;
  --cursorY: 50vh;
  --cursorX2: 50vw;
  --cursorY2: 50vh;
  --animationDuration: 10s;
  --animationDelay: 15s;
}

:root:before {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-blend-mode: normal, overlay;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: auto, auto, cover;
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(
      circle 16vmax at var(--cursorX2) var(--cursorY2),
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 30%,
      rgba(0,5,5,.1) 40%,
      rgba(5,5,0,.5) 60%,
      rgba(0,0,0,.75) 70%,
      rgba(0,0,0,.95) 100%
    ),
    radial-gradient(
      circle 12vmax at var(--cursorX) var(--cursorY),
      rgba(255,255,255,1) 30%,
      rgba(255,255,255,.3) 50%,
      rgba(255,255,255,.05) 100%
    ),
    url(https://handluggageonly.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Sewers-of-Paris-2.jpg);

  animation: torch var(--animationDuration) linear var(--animationDelay) infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes torch {
    0%, 1%, 2%, 3%, 4%, 5%, 20%, 21%, 60%, 61%, 62%, 100% { background-image:
      radial-gradient(
        circle 16vmax at var(--cursorX2) var(--cursorY2),
        rgba(0,0,0,0) 30%,
        rgba(0,5,5,.1) 40%,
        rgba(5,5,0,.5) 60%,
        rgba(0,0,0,.75) 70%,
        rgba(0,0,0,.95) 100%
      ),
      radial-gradient(
        circle 12vmax at var(--cursorX) var(--cursorY),
        rgba(255,255,255,1) 30%,
        rgba(255,255,255,.3) 50%,
        rgba(255,255,255,.05) 100%
      ),
      url(https://handluggageonly.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Sewers-of-Paris-2.jpg);
    }
  
    0.5%, 1.5%, 60.5% { background-image:
      radial-gradient(
        circle 12vmax at var(--cursorX2) var(--cursorY2),
        rgba(0,0,0,0) 30%,
        rgba(0,5,5,.1) 40%,
        rgba(5,5,0,.5) 60%,
        rgba(0,0,0,.75) 70%,
        rgba(0,0,0,.95) 100%
      ),
      radial-gradient(
        circle 8vmax at var(--cursorX) var(--cursorY),
        rgba(255,255,255,1) 30%,
        rgba(255,255,255,.3) 50%,
        rgba(255,255,255,.05) 100%
      ),
      url(https://handluggageonly.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Sewers-of-Paris-2.jpg);
    }
  
    2.5%, 3.5%, 4.5%, 20.5%, 61.5% { background-image:
      radial-gradient(
        circle 8vmax at var(--cursorX) var(--cursorY),
        rgba(0,0,0,0) 30%,
        rgba(0,5,5,.1) 40%,
        rgba(5,5,0,.5) 60%,
        rgba(0,0,0,.75) 70%,
        rgba(0,0,0,.95) 100%
      ),
      radial-gradient(
        circle 4vmax at var(--cursorX) var(--cursorY),
        rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,
        rgba(255,255,255,.5) 50%,
        rgba(255,255,255,.05) 100%
      ),
      url(https://handluggageonly.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Sewers-of-Paris-2.jpg);
    }
}
```

You can also access it here: https://codepen.io/Danziger/pen/VyOZpy

Keep in mind it has some limitations though, as the overlay will cover all the page, so the effect is limited to the background image and different gradients added to it.

**Even if you replace the pseudoelement with a `<div>` and add content in it, that content will not be affected by the blend mode.**

However, it might be possible to achieve that using [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode). You can check out the cursor on my website, which also uses animations/transitions between its different shapes or states and [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) so that the cursor blends with any element on the page, not just with the background of one specific element:

Check it out here: https://gmzcodes.com/.

‍ Check the code here: https://github.com/Danziger/gmzcodes

Lastly, here you can see another answer with a simpler custom cursor that might be all you need in most cases and might help you understand how to do it: [CSS - Custom cursor that changes depending on hovered element flickers when moving left to right but not right to left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50538768/css-custom-cursor-that-changes-depending-on-hovered-element-flickers-when-movi/50538792)

Comment: Please don't answer off topic questions. It only encourages them. Not all questions can or should be answered.

Comment: @Rob I think if the answer is non-trivial, and this one might not be, depending on one's experience, it's ok to provide some guidance on possible implementations, as long as we don't code it for them, the same way it is ok to suggest possible improvements on questions about performance, which are less likely to get a specific answer. Anyway, someone already has...

Comment: He is asking for code and the question is off topic. It will be closed for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

**edit**: as @Rob has said below, always try to answer questions on your own first. This is merely an implementation suggestion and should not be copied mindlessly.

---

I think you can create a CSS element with a radial gradient that you keep under your mouse with JS.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var flashlight = document.querySelector('#flashlight');
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    flashlight.style.left = (event.pageX-25) + 'px';
    flashlight.style.top = (event.pageY-25) + 'px';
  });
};
```

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url('https://scontent-lga3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/12140762_1159067420823544_4471328164031495581_n.jpg?oh=78a75ea8fe74295d8087eff97dbcef5a&oe=5AF0967D');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}
#mask {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#flashlight {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: radial-gradient(white 0%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<!-- darken background -->
<div id='mask'></div>

<!-- flashlight effect -->
<div id='flashlight'></div>
```

Comment: Where is the image that is darkened?

Comment: @Rob What image? The background is dark, and the cursor should have a flashlight-type effect, correct?

Comment: He said he wants the image to darken

Comment: @Rob I guess I read that wrong. That should be simple with a partially-transparent div over the image. I'll edit that in.

Comment: Don't waste your time. The question is off topic and will be closed. You shouldn't be writing code. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: @Rob I realized that after I posted, but it seemed fun to implement what he asked at first glance.

Comment: It only encourages others to break SO's policy and rules which state such question shouldn't even be answered at all.

Answer (score 0):

There aren’t many options using only CSS. You can check out [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp) where they detail all the types of cursors you can use. But those are not relevant to your use case as it’s just changing the icon.

You might need to look into a JS solution to track the cursor position. [Check out this StackOverflow answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7790764/7012894)

After you know where the cursor is, you can create a div:

```
#cursor-background {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
```

You can then try and change the position of this div using:

```
document.getElementById("cursor-background").style.transform = "translate(“ + X + “,” + Y + “)";
```

Where X and Y are your desired position on the screen.

To avoid it looking jumpy, add a transition property in the CSS of “cursor-background”:

```
 transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
```

I haven’t tested any of this out, just trying to provide guidance as to which direction you should take.

As for the background, make it whichever color you want it to be. The flashlight effect will come from the light div hovering over your dark background.