# Universal windows applicatation webview get google maps event

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am creating a UWA and I need to interact with google maps. I have added Google maps at a webview and I am capable to add/remove markers via javascript and InvokeScriptAsync. Now I need to handle events on the opposite way. For example show at UWA the lon and lat of the mouse location or by selecting a marker to do some work at the UWA.

is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already using InvokeScriptAsync, then you know how to inject [JavaScript code that tracks mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790725/javascript-track-mouse-position).

To send the tracked mouse locations back to your app, you can use the [WebView.ScriptNotify](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.scriptnotify) event on the C# side to receive events from JavaScript via [window.external.notify()](http://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.com/2016/01/windows-store-apps-how-to-communicate.html)

Note that you will need to add the Google Map page's URI to the ApplicationContentUriRules section of your app's manifest.

I haven't used Google Maps before, so I don't know this url.