# How can I get the cursor coordinates properly ? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I get the coordinates of the cursor on the screen properly ?

I tried using `event.clientX` and `event.clientY` however it only works in certain cases .
If I try to make a special function for it it works

```
 stage = new createjs.Stage("myCanvas");
 circle = new createjs.Shape();
 circle.graphics.beginFill("red").drawCircle(0, 0, 40);
 createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", handleTick);

 function handleTick() {
     if (circle.x > stage.canvas.width) { circle.x = 0; }
     stage.addChild(circle);
     stage.update();
 }

 document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(){circle.x = event.clientX,circle.y = event.clientY});
```

However when I try to include it in my function `handleTick()` I get a thon of erros :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientX' of undefined
```

Are there any other things I can use for this ? And why don't it work in my the `handleTick()` function ?

Comment: You say _"when i try include it in my handler"_, which handler?

Comment: Sorry Im new to js . I meant the function called handleTick()

Comment: How do you setup the handler? The event object is passed as an argument, but your handler doesn't have one defined, ie `function handleTick(event)`

Comment: It's saying event is undefined. Try add it to your function. `function(event){circle.x...`

Comment: Ah, so use `event.clientX` in your function and add `event` as a function parameter, e.g. `function handleTick(event) {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addEventListener` should provide the `event` for you, if you do like this, and add `event` as a function argument. With that you should be able to get the mouse position and assign its values to your `circle` object.

```
function handleTick(event) {
     circle.x = event.clientX;
     if (circle.x > stage.canvas.width) { circle.x = 0; }
     stage.addChild(circle);
     stage.update();
}
```

---

If it won't, then you need to capture the mouse move and store its values in a global variable, and here is a great post showing additional ways how to do that.

- [Javascript - Track mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790725/javascript-track-mouse-position)