# Right click menu not displaying in correct position

Tags: javascript, html, css, contextmenu, right-click

I am trying to create a edit and delete option for a list of items for which i have made it display when user right click on that list item.

```js
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var x = e.offsetX;
  var y = e.offsetY;
  var d = document.getElementById("context-menu");
  d.style.display = "block";
  d.style.left = x + 'px';
  d.style.top = y + 'px';
  console.log(x, y);
}, false);
```

```css
#context-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  color: blue;
}

.listItems li {
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="listItems">
  <li>I am list one</li>
  <li>I am list two</li>
  <li>I am list three</li>
  <li>I am list four</li>
</ul>

<ul id="context-menu">
  <li> Edit </li>
  <li> Delete </li>
</ul>
```

And the **jsfiddle** link was, https://jsfiddle.net/dmfvz5qw/1/

Here when i make a right click, the **id** named `context-menu` is not displaying nearby the mouse arrow and it is showing at more top of the clicked list.

I am in the need to display the `context-menu` nearby right clicked position rather than any other position.

Kindly help me to fix the issue and also i am in the need of result in **Pure Javascript**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use clientX and clientY here,

If you want to learn more about the positioning using body scroll position too, then refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/7790764/2630817

```js
 document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 document.getElementById("context-menu").display = 'none';     
 var x = e.clientX ;
 var y = e.clientY;
 var d = document.getElementById("context-menu");
 d.style.display = "block";
 d.style.left = x+'px';
 d.style.top = y+'px';
 console.log(x,y);
}, false);
```

```css
#context-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  color: blue;
  padding: 0;
  width:50px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="listItems">
  <li>I am list one</li>
  <li>I am list two</li>
  <li>I am list three</li>
  <li>I am list four</li>
</ul>
<ul id="context-menu">
  <li> Edit </li>
  <li> Delete </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: May i know why you have added jquery in html? But there is no code written in jquery?

Answer (score 2):

Please use `clientX` and `clientY` instead:

```
var x = e.clientX;
var y = e.clientY;
```