# Get cursor position at frequent interval

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, mouselistener

I'm trying to get mouse cursor current position at frequent interval.

```
function checkMousePos(ev){
            alert(true);
            var x = ev.clientX,
            y = ev.clientY;
            alert('' + x + ' ' + y);
}

setInterval(checkMousePos, 500);
```

This code alerts `true`, but never `x` and `y`.

What am I not doing right ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790725/javascript-track-mouse-position

Comment: `ev` is not `event` in your case.

Comment: @PranavCBalan - I think is is not a dupe...

Comment: @Rayon what do you mean ?

Comment: @Rayon : why not? It somewhat answers the question

Comment: @PranavCBalan The linked post is with mousemove. I'm looking to get position at regular interval, with or without (mouse)move.

Comment: @tmpsp52 - `ev` parameter which is being expected as `event` is not `event` in your case..

Comment: @tmpsp52 :  check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7790764/3037257

Comment: `ev = ev || window.event;`

Comment: @Rayon Anyway I can make it event in my case ?

Comment: @tmpsp52 -  As your handler is not invoked by some event of mouse, you can not actually. Global `window.event` could be used though as suggested by *Pranav*

Comment: Thank you both. Let me look to this global 'window.event' then.

Comment: @PranavCBalan Thank you! But it seems it also does not alert x and y.

Comment: @tmpsp52 :  try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/7790764/3037257

Comment: @PranavCBalan : Thank you. This is instructive. I understand what I'm trying to achieve is not really possible with a setinterval method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When debugging something you far better using something like `console.log(myVariable)` and then viewing it in the console. In your case `ev` not being pass by your interval and there for it's undefined. What seems like this:

```
var x;
var y;

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event){
    x = event.pageX;
    y = event.pageY;
})

function checkMousePos(){
    console.log("Cursor at: " + x + ", " + y);
}

setInterval(checkMousePos, 500);
```

Although it's usually not the best solution.

Comment: Not in relation to your answer but in regard to your output location. If I am doing a quick bit of debugging I still throw things out to document.title. It's a bit old school but it stops you needing to swap between the browser and the dev tools (normally where the console exists) to see the result.

Comment: Thank you Alex. This results in Cursor at: undefined, undefined.