# How to track the position of the mouse on X-axis in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to know how to track the position of the mouse on X-axis on the screen. Based on limited knowledge of Java/Processing, it is something similar to mouseX in Java. In addition, I want to rotate an image element based on the position of the mouse on X-axis. It would be nice to receive some pieces of advice.

Comment: Check this out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790725/javascript-track-mouse-position

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790725/javascript-track-mouse-position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Track the mouse position in the X axis is done with an `eventListener` (the `mousemove` event)
- This listener uses a callback function which should change the `transform` (rotate) css property of your element.

```
    // DOM accessor to your HTML element
    const rotatingE = document.getElementById('my-rotating-el')

    // Event Listener
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
      // Callback function
      const mX = e.clientX / window.innerWidth * 360

      rotatingE.style.transform = 'rotate('+ mX +'deg)'
    })
```

I've made a quick example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/marLn1bv/)

Answer (score 0):

a popular library/framework that is similar to Processing is P5.js (developed by the same people but for javascript) which can handle this for you

but in vanilla javascript, you would need an event listener

```
var mouse = {
    x: undefined, 
    y:undefined
};

window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
    mouse.x = event.x;
    mouse.y = event.y;
});
```

what this does is listens for a mouse movement, and then records it to an object

then to take the mouseX position you can write

```
var mouseX = mouse.x;
```

or you can directly take it from

```
mouse.x;
//still the same
```