# How to keep track of mouse events and position using selenium and javascript in python?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am working to get the element details while clicking on that element inside the selenium web driver in python by executing a javascript function on the page.

But it is not working as I expected, even I have used the async method to get the element details from javascript to python. But I still can't able to get the element details in serverside python code.

Please provide a better solution for this case.

**sample code**

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def mouseevent(driver):
            while true:
                mouse =driver.execute_script(''' 
                    var x= onclick = function(e){
                        return e.target;
                    }
                ''')
                print(mouse)

driver=webdriver.Chrome(Chrome)

driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

tasks = [
    asyncio.ensure_future(mouseevent(driver))]
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
loop.close()
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What does _But it is not working as I expected_ mean, exactly? Do you have a **specific** issue?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Thanks for reply. How do i get the element details while clicking on a page in selenium webdriver. I am not able to access the element details that returned from javascript.

Comment: I feel like I'm repeating myself, but what does _element details_ mean, exactly?

Comment: I am having a javascript function  ** onclick = function(e){ return e.target;}** that returns the clicked html element. I can able to see that clicked html element details in the web browser and i cant able to get those html element details in python.Please refer  the above sample code

Comment: you javascript code only assings function to variable `onclick` but it will never run it when you click. Maybe try this code first in console in web browser. `onclick` is only normal variable and has nothing to do with clicking. Maybe you meas something like `$('body').click(function(e){...})` with `jQuery` ?

Comment: Or maybe `some_object_in_html.onclick = function(e){...}` ? And you should assign it only once and it should put value in some global variable like `function(e){ global_variable = e.target; }` and you should use loop only to check value in this variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is better method but this code  works for me.

---

First I create variable `window.x` with default value at start so I can check its value all the time - even if I don't click any element.

```
driver.execute_script('window.x = null;')
```

Later I assign to `body` function which will be executed when I click `body` - it will assign value to `window.x`

```
driver.execute_script('document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) { window.x = e.target;})')
```

And in loop I only check value in this variable.

```
while True:
    print(driver.execute_script('return window.x'))
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

---

It would need to check if value was changed between loop or it should run function which copy value from `window.x` to ie. `window.y`, next it clearn `window.x` and it returns `window.y` - this way it will get value only once.

```
while True:
    print(driver.execute_script('window.y = window.x; window.x = null; return window.y'))
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

---

```
import selenium.webdriver
import time

url = 'https://stackoverflow.com'
driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

driver.execute_script('window.x = null;')

driver.execute_script('document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) { window.x = e.target;})')

while True:
    print(driver.execute_script('window.y = window.x; window.x = null; return window.y'))
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

---

**EDIT:** I found answers which should better resolve problem: [Javascript - Track mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790725/javascript-track-mouse-position)