# Get text cursor (caret) position in viewport space?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, caret, draftjs

Is it possible to get the position of the carets absolute screen space position? My intention is to hide the caret and replace it with a custom component that may 'fly' around the screen.

Comment: Do you mean the cursor?

Comment: @user0101 probably a better way to describe it hehe

Comment: How about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790725/javascript-track-mouse-position?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript - Track mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790725/javascript-track-mouse-position)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get caret position using the Selection API, getting the ranges (`collapsed==true` when just the caret is showing), and their client rects.

```
document.addEventListener('selectionchange', () => {
  console.log(getSelection()?.getRangeAt(0)?.getClientRects()?.[0])
)
```

These client rects are in screen space, so you probably also want to track document scroll and get the rects again.

```
{x: 286.796875, y: 209, width: 0, height: 19, top: 209, …}
```