# Is there a way to check the mouse location with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

So while making a website for trolls, I had the idea to make the website move a button that takes the user to another website and clicking it is the only way forward. Is there a way to check for the location of the cursor on the website to make the button change location, or is there a way to randomize the location of the cursor when it gets into a specific range?

Comment: There is a possibility to get the pointer location but not to manipulate it.

Comment: Read up for that on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790725/javascript-track-mouse-position

Comment: One thing you could do though is to hide the cursor and draw a fake one that you can control.

Answer (score 3):

You can detect the location of the mouse by listening to the `onmousemove` event.

```js
document.onmousemove = (ev) => {
  if (ev.clientX < 100) {
    document.querySelector('button').classList.add('moved');
  } else {
    document.querySelector('button').classList.remove('moved');
  }
}
```

```css
.moved {
  transform: translate(200px);
}
```

```html
<button>Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

all you need is onmousemove global handler. But you must be very careful - every even small move of mouse calls the event, so you function should not be very heavy. There is a way to prevent any problems by using throttling.