# rotate div based on mouse position

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm working on a javascript game where you drive a car based on where your mouse is, (so it moves towards your mouse).

But right now its just a rectangle that follows your mouse. I want it to rotate towarts the mouse, (for example if you have a rectangle that is 100px wide and 50px high and the left side is white and the right side is black, the black side should always face the cursor).

i tried making if statements for some positions of the mouse but after a hour of programming, i figured out this was going to take weeks like this. Does anybody know a better and/or easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `transform: rotate(angle)`. And calculate angle using [atan2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2)

```
const mousePos = { x: 10, y: 10 }
const carPos = { x: 30, y: 20 }
const vector = { x: mousePos.x - carPos.x, y: mousePos.y - carPos.y }
const angle = Math.atan2(vector.y, vector.x) * 180 / Math.PI;
```

Maybe you will need to add 90 degrees or something like that. Untested.

Comment: Im guesing that const carpos isn't enough. do i need to const it with a document.queryselector("#car"); and the same for mousepos?

Comment: Here you will learn how to get mouse position. It doesn't have to be const or an object. You just need x and y positions.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790725/javascript-track-mouse-position

Comment: it works but the rotation isn't perfect there is a problem with the math, could you please double check it?

Comment: What do you mean by *isn't perfect*?

Comment: nvm i found the problem, thanks for all of your help!

Comment: hello sir, i have one last question. When the top and left positions of the object aren't the same it doesnt work, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @a-bad-js-developer what do you mean by this?

Comment: If the top and left position aren't the same the div wil move very slow at some points and very fast at others

Comment: Add half width of the div to the carPos.x and half height of the div to the carPos.y

Comment: that makes it worse

Comment: Do you have some online example somewhere?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223015/discussion-between-a-bad-js-developer-and-konrad-linkowski).