# Write specific text on the screen with a mouse movement

Tags: javascript, html, css

**I want when i move the mouse write specific text on the screen**

**example:"hello world"**

[this is image (example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xkx53.jpg)

i have code but he is not what I want

script --->

```
window.focus();
  const output = document.querySelector('output');
  let text = 'A';
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', ({
    x,
    y
  }) => {
    if (x > 100) text = 'W';
    if (x > 400) text = 'X';
    if (y > 100) text = 'B';
    if (y > 400) text = 'J';
    output.textContent += text;
  });
```

please help me!!

Comment: where should the text be displayed? right on the cursor location?, and it creates a new text on every pixel movement?

Comment: @RamondeVries yes. wherever you move the mouse, the text will appear

Comment: @RamondeVries can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note that I changed for `document.querySelector('#output');` because I used a div with id "output". If you are using and `<output>` tag (?), keep it as in your original code.

Here the letter will move with the page scroll, if you want to keep at the same place while scrolling, use `position: static;` instead.

```js
  const output = document.querySelector('#output');
  let text = 'Hello World!';
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', ({
      x,
      y
    }) => {
      output.innerHTML += '<div style="position: absolute; left: ' + x + 'px; top: ' + y + 'px;">' + text + '</div>';
  });
```

```html
<div id="output" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
```

Comment: Just as a side note: I quite like your solution as it's based on the vague sample code but this approach creates a zillion new `<div>` elements.

Comment: but i want only text. this is word

Comment: @obscure yes I reckon that's something to play with rather than an optimal proper code, but apart from using things like `<canvas>`, this is the way. It's more a teaching answer because it shows the OP what the code missed. Still not really more divs than most WordPress themes I've seen ;)

Comment: @kokiwebaaa what do you mean by "this is word"?

Comment: @Kaddath Nice idea nevertheless - `<canvas>` was the only thing that has come into my mind.

Comment: @Kaddath i want print only one string. example "hello world" yous example only are letters. w,x,b,j

Comment: @kokiwebaaa I kept what was in your original code, if you want a fixed string, put it in `let text = 'A';` and remove all your `if` (edited the answer)

Answer (score 0):

i have modifyied this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7790764/9496199 to have the text hello world displayed instead of a dot, hope this helps.

code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
  <style>
    body {
      height: 3000px;
    }
    .dot {
      width: fit-content;
      height: fit-content;
      background-color: invisible;
      position: absolute;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  (function() {
    "use strict";

    document.onmousemove = handleMouseMove;
    function handleMouseMove(event) {
      var dot, eventDoc, doc, body, pageX, pageY;
      
      event = event || window.event; // IE-ism
      
      // If pageX/Y aren't available and clientX/Y
      // are, calculate pageX/Y - logic taken from jQuery
            // Calculate pageX/Y if missing and clientX/Y available
      if (event.pageX == null && event.clientX != null) {
        eventDoc = (event.target && event.target.ownerDocument) || document;
        doc = eventDoc.documentElement;
        body = eventDoc.body;

        event.pageX = event.clientX +
          (doc && doc.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0) -
          (doc && doc.clientLeft || body && body.clientLeft || 0);
        event.pageY = event.clientY +
          (doc && doc.scrollTop  || body && body.scrollTop  || 0) -
          (doc && doc.clientTop  || body && body.clientTop  || 0 );
      }

      // Add a dot to follow the cursor
      dot = document.createElement('div');
      dot.className = "dot";
      dot.innerHTML = "hello world";
      dot.style.left = event.pageX + "px";
      dot.style.top = event.pageY + "px";
      document.body.appendChild(dot);
    }
  })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```