# How to make a 3D object follow cursor in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, 3d, blender, fbx

I'm still new to web design and I am about to make my portfolio. I'm a designer who has worked in 2D and 3D art and would like my main page to show a 3D rendering of myself, that follows the mouse. Much in the style of the following website:

https://wannabe-store.webflow.io/

Does anyone have any suggestion on where to begin with this? What filetype do i render(i use blender), Can it be embedded in HTML? can the movement be coded in javascript perhaps?

Thank you for your patience, any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked website used **Canvas** to show the 3D model following arrow cursor. The following links might help you to achieve some of your goals.

[Javascript - Track mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790725/javascript-track-mouse-position)

https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-mouse-coordinates/

https://tympanus.net/codrops/2019/10/14/how-to-create-an-interactive-3d-character-with-three-js/

Thank you!