# How to track mouse position in pixels using AlpineJS

Tags: html, tailwind-css, alpine.js

I'm using AlpineJS and would like to track the coordinates of the mouse cursor within a div.

Context: I'm trying to apply a radial blur hover effect using TailwindCSS emanating from the cursor position. I can't use TailwindCSS specific tools for this (e.g., `group`) because I need to know the exact x/y coordinates of the cursor. See [the Tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/top-right-bottom-left#arbitrary-values).

```html
<div x-data="{ mouseX: '...px', mouseY: '...px' }">
  
   ...

</div>
```

Any ideas on how I can get mouseX and mouseY to update automatically based on mouse location in pixels? Note that I need mouseX/mouseY to include both the position as integer and the string 'px'.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method is just applying an Alpine data using a standard mouse tracking script:

Refer to [docs](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-data).

```js
export default() => ({
    mouseX: 0,
    mouseY: 0,
    mouseXAsPx: '0px',
    mouseYAsPx: '0px',

    init() {
        // Watch the values to automatically update the PX variants
        this.$watch('mouseX', (value) => this.mouseXAsPx = value + 'px');
        this.$watch('mouseY', (value) => this.mouseYAsPx = value + 'px');

        document.onmousemove = handleMouseMove;
        function handleMouseMove(event) {
            var eventDoc, doc, body;

            event = event || window.event; // IE-ism

            // If pageX/Y aren't available and clientX/Y are,
            // calculate pageX/Y - logic taken from jQuery.
            // (This is to support old IE)
            if (event.pageX == null && event.clientX != null) {
                eventDoc = (event.target && event.target.ownerDocument) || document;
                doc = eventDoc.documentElement;
                body = eventDoc.body;

                event.pageX = event.clientX +
                  (doc && doc.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0) -
                  (doc && doc.clientLeft || body && body.clientLeft || 0);
                event.pageY = event.clientY +
                  (doc && doc.scrollTop  || body && body.scrollTop  || 0) -
                  (doc && doc.clientTop  || body && body.clientTop  || 0 );
            }

            this.mouseX = event.pageX;
            this.mouseY = event.pageY;

            this.applyBlur();
        }
    }
    applyBlur() {
         // Do something here
    }
});
```

```js
import Blur from '{pathToScript}/blur.js';

Alpine.data('blur', Blur);

Alpine.start();
```

```html
<div x-data="blur"></div>
```

Credit for mouse positioning: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7790764/14793358