# get position of mouse inside interval to move a div with mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to move a div with the movement of the mouse cursor, but can't understand how to get the newly updated mouse position within my timeout. Maybe there is a simpler way.

```
var t;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").on("mousedown", ".heading", function (e) {
        $("body").data("header_click", true);

        if ($("body").data("header_click")) {

            var container = $("#dialog");

            container.css("position", "absolute");

            t = setInterval(function(){

                //some way to get mouse position
                var pos = container.position();

                container.css({

                    top: "",//set based on mouse position
                    left: "",//set based on mouse position

                });

            }, 100);    

        }else{
            document.clearInterval(t);
        }

    });
});

$("body").on("mousedown", ".heading", function (e) {
    $("body").data("header_click", false);
});
```

The solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608498/capture-mouse-position-on-setinterval-in-javascript) did not work for me.

Comment: Just wondering why not use the jquery ui lib for draggable? http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: @Chausser because I want to manually just run this from the console for now, then turn it into a bookmarklet probably. It is for a page I can't change I just want to add the ability to drag a modal.

Comment: AFAIK, there's no way to query the mouse position - it's only available in the event object. So, instead of polling you'd have to setup a `mousemove` handler and put the dragging logic there.

Comment: @thg435 I came to the same conclusion. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to bind to the mouse move event and update a document variable.

```
var currentMousePos = { x: -1, y: -1 };
$(document).on('mousemove', function(event) {
    currentMousePos.x = event.pageX;
    currentMousePos.y = event.pageY;
});
```

Then use those positions relative to the absolute positions of the element you are wanting to drag to calculate and update the elements new position.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").on("mousedown", ".heading", function (e) {
        $("body").data("header_click", true);
        if ($("body").data("header_click")) {
            var container = $("#dialog");
            container.css("position", "absolute");

            var containerPos = container.pos();
            var mouseTopOffset = containerPos.top - currentMousePos.y;
            var mouseLeftOffset = containerPos.left - currentMousePos.x;

            container.css("left", mouseTopOffset +"px");
            container.css("top", mouseLeftOffset +"px");
        }
    }
}
```

I havent really tested this but in theory should do what you need.